# Couldn't find the package.json file

Tags: reactjs, installation, package.json, installation-package

Working on my React portfolio project and encountered this message on the terminal. I do have package.json file in my folder. Not sure why it popped out. I have installed yarn and npx create-react-app@3.4.1 course2portfolio--->(my project folder name)

Here is the message shown in the terminal on VS code:
Claires-MacBook-Pro:course2portfolio ginobili20g$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.10
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/Users/ginobili20g/Desktop/course2portfolio"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Claires-MacBook-Pro:course2portfolio ginobili20g$

Comment: can u post image of your folder structure

Comment: can you elaborate plz?

Comment: Did you cd into the app root directory after creating it? You have to run that command in the directory package.jsin is in.

Comment: @DanOswalt I didn't recall doing that. Very new to coding still. I was following along my bootcamp installation process.

Comment: Do you see a folder named `course2portfolio` inside the `/Users/ginobili20g/Desktop/course2portfolio` folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by looking at your image, I realized that u opened the wrong folder in vs code, pls open course2portfolio folder, thats why the error...
you need to open course2portfolio and then click on open....

Comment: I didn't see package-lock.json.

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATgqn.jpg. 

here is my terminal and folders on VS codes.

Comment: by looking at your image, I realized that u opened the wrong folder in vs code, pls open course2portfolio folder, thats why the error... you need to open course2portfolio and then click on open....

Comment: pls upvote and accept ans if correct :)  .. need points for bounty

Comment: I have upvoted but it doesn't show? newbie at stack overflow.